# Setting Name of PDF When Printing

Tags: node.js, header, title, mime

I don't know if this is possible or not so bear with me.

I've got an application that serves a PDF after sending some data to the server with a POST.  Currently I'm sending the PDF to the browser by setting the `Content-disposition`, `Content-length`, and `Content-type` headers.

## Example:

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attatchment; filename="' + filename + '"')
if (stats && stats.size) then res.setHeader('Content-Length', stats.size)
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf')

stream.pipe(res)
// stream is a filestream from somewhere
```

Doing it this way works fine for setting the file name if you want to save the PDF.  Because of some PDF encoding issues and Apple products, we now want to open the PDF directly in the browser.  Users will then print as PDF to save it so that Apple readers can view the PDF correctly.

Is it possible to set the Print as PDF name?  It seems that it uses URL and title to determine what the printed name is.  If that's the case, is there a way of setting the title with the headers or otherwise setting the title while still loading the PDF in the browser?

Comment: Does your PDF have a title set on it's metadata? I'd be surprised if Apple didn't look at that.

Comment: See here for details :http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/print/auto_insert_metadata

Comment: I'm not sure, I have to look at that.  I believe this is a browser issue, as viewing PDF browser view behavior generally is handled by the browser. (Chrome has their in-house solution, Firefox uses PDF.js.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking a more [generalized question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789851/set-title-of-inline-file), it would seem it's impossible.

I'm fairly certain the title behavior for files opened directly in the browser.  If you attempt to save the file with the above headers, the filename will be populated correctly.