# Set Title of Inline File?

Tags: html, http-headers, filenames

I'm forcing a download to be handled by the browser by setting the header `Content-disposition` to `inline;`

Is there a way of setting the title this way?  Currently it looks like the browser auto-fills it with the URL of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can specify the filename just like you'd do for `content-disposition: attachment`, i.e. like this:

```
Content-disposition: inline; filename="foo.bar"
```

See this post for some useful information about this header: [How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when setting it to `inline;`  After loading the file via POST, here's my `Content-disposition` header:  `Content-disposition:inline; filename="foo.bar"`  The title of the page is still gets set to `localhost:3000/blah/blah/blah`  If I try and save the file, the filename is set, but I'm hoping to set the tab's title.

Comment: Ah, that's impossible. A file has no title in the browser.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible, just make the end of your URL to contain the filename, be sure to URLEncode it, most browsers will ignore the queryString

localhost:3000/blah/blah/blah/Attachment%3A%20Screen%20Shot.png/?id=1670674338147205293

Tab Display = "Attachment: Screen Shot.png"

Works fine on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera . . . Safari displays either the domain or the entire URL depending on your settings

Comment: 2 years later . . . no longer works in Chrome or Opera, still works in Firefox